# Can I run MS-Word/Excel when I don't have an internet connection?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I've paid for Microsoft Home & Student Version of Word/Excel 2010 and I can't use them unless I'm tethered to the internet; how can enable use of these programs when I'm not connected?  Is there a full download of the product? Or some macro to force the download of all the features while I am connected?

Most of the time they work, but on occasion it will try and download new "features" when I do simple formatting changes, such as, applying a style.  Rather than determining that the I don't have an internet connection, it craps out and locks up the program.

Comment: This question is confusing. Are you using the ONLINE version of MS Office products. i.e. the Office Web Apps mentioned in Xaviers link, OR did you buy and install Microsoft Office onto your computer? Do you have Office Starter? Were your running the FreeTrial of the full version of Office 2010? To me. If you bought the full version of MS Word and Excel and installed them, they are not web dependent. Need more info.

Comment: @VISQL Well, I did write that I paid for my version, though didn't specify what (Home and Student) in my original post; so I wouldn't be using a "Free" version of anything.  And I'd agree, a purchased version of MS OFfice shouldn't be web dependant, but in my case it is.

Comment: Is this what you bought?  http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Office-Home-Student-2010/dp/B00337D8U6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1336682108&sr=8-1

Comment: @Tog Yes, but I did a download and not a media purchase.

Comment: Have you tried completely deactivating your network connection? If the network interface is active, but there is no connection, the computer might hang while waiting for an answer that will never come. Try deactivating the network connection under "Network connections" in the Windows configuration.